# IIS websites hosting and OWA configuration

Tags: configuration

hi i want to know how i can configure my IIS server to host more than 3 websites. And i have configured Outlook web access but if i want to access it using the FQDN it is giving me a 404 error but if i use an IP address it is working, when i check my DNS server it seems to be fine because it is able to resolve internal and external queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using host headers. Here is a visual guide: http://www.visualwin.com/host-header/.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure sites in IIS to listen for traffic in two ways. Firstly you can configure it to listen on an IP address, or all IP address on a particular port, usually port 80. When you have a site that does that, not other site can also listen for all traffic on that IP(s) and port, the only thing it can listen for is a particular host header, which we will come onto in a minute. In IIS configuration it would look like this:

[image: All IP's bound]

This site in IIS is bound to listen on all IP's on the machine, on port 80.

Another method, and one you need to use if you have other sites listening for all traffic, is host headers. We can supply a host header for a site so that this site listens on an IP or set of IP's, on a port, but only for a particular host header, such as www.domain.com. Any traffic directed to that IP and port on the server, that is a request for www.domain.com, is handled by that site, requests for say www.seconddomain.com are ignored by this site.

This way you can have multiple sites listening on the same IP, without conflicting, and only serving pages for their designated site and host headers.

This site below is set to listen on all IP's on port 80, but only for requests for www.domain.com and domain.com

[image: Host headers]

Answer (score 0):

Just by chance: Do you have forms authentication on in Exchange? I've run into errors when trying to access OWA without forms authentication. It's a common thing to overlook when setting up OWA.

I'm sure it's not likely the solution to your specific query, but I thought someone should mention it just in case.